# How to convert normal number to a number with power.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I wanted to ask all of you how can I convert a normal number to a number with a power. It does not have to be the power of $2$ but it must be a power. For example :

$16$ convert to $ 4^{2}$

$4$ convert to $ 2^{2} $

Thanks.

Comment: And $17$ converts to $\sqrt{17}^2$?

Comment: Most numbers can't be written this way, at least if you want to be raising an integer to an integer power.  Also, what would you do with something like 64 - is it $4^3$ or $2^6$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Answer (score 1):

To write a number as a power, you can try to factorise it into primes. For example, $$225=3\times 3\times 5\times 5=3\times 5\times 3\times 5=(3\times 5)^2=15^2$$ or $$216=2\times 2\times 2\times 3\times 3\times 3=2\times 3\times 2\times 3\times 2\times 3=(2\times 3)^3=6^3.$$

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach would be something like :

$$a=a^{1}=a^{\frac{n}{n}}={(a^{\frac{1}{n}})}^n.$$

Assuming the $n$-th root exists for $a$, you will get an integer raised to another integer this way.  For example given $a=16$,

$16={(16^{\frac{1}{2}})}^2=4^2$ for    $n=2$

$16={(16^{\frac{1}{4}})}^4=2^4$ for    $n=4$.

Comment: Note that you only need to try $n$ up to $\log_2(a)$, so this is fairly efficient, too.